# Postgres FDW - Triggers to update local schema when remote schema has a DML

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgres-fdw

I have a client website that has a Postgres backend which I consider as my remote database. I use FDWs to connect from my local database to the remote DB.

So what I have is :

Remote DB ->remote Schema -> Has a table called remote_work_packages

On my database, this would after I create an FDW server -

Local DB -> Local schema -> foreign table foreign_work_packages

Now as I said the client website connects to the Remote DB , and whenever there is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE into remote_work_packages, then I want some functions to be triggered on my local schema.

Please note , I do not have access to create a trigger on the Remote table.

Is there a way this can be achieved. I know since release 9.4, that it is possible to create triggers on foreign tables. But there is no way I could find out how to track activity on the remote itself. Is there a way to track staying on the local DB. Please advise.